# How can I create recurring events in Jorte?

Tags: jorte

That is, an event that happens once a week, once a month, once a year, etc. Pretty sure I've read that this can be done, but I can't figure out how. (I've also read that this app has quite a learning curve!)

I don't want this calendar linked with my Google calendar, so creating it there isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

In the Event creation dialog box I have a "Repetition" drop-down box with all of those options.  This is using Jorte 1.2.31

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by selecting the desired repetition from the combo box. Here some screenshots:

[image: Repeat Select Dropdown]
[image: Repeat Select]

[Jorte changelog](http://www.jorte.net/english/update.html) does not have entry that describe the recurring events addition so I suppose this feature coule be there since first releases.